# How to run python file within flask?

Tags: python, flask

In my flask application I have a so called 'about' page, from this about page i want to run this python script.

This is the script:
https://github.com/stakeinlinkies/sendwithasmile/blob/master/sendsmile.py and it has 2 dependency xml files.

this is the content of my about page:

```
{% extends "layout.html"%}
{% block content%}
<h1>about</h1>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >Start A.I.</button>
{% endblock content %}
```

When I run the program in the command line the prgramm turns on the webcam and a video window pops up and than detects for a smile.

I want to run this on the website so i want the video window to be rendered on my about page.
How can i achieve this.

Comment: You need to read this [Quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/). Basically you have to setup a view that the template can request a response from.

Comment: i dont see anything in the flsk tutorial that explains that

Comment: Well I mentioned the Quickstart not the Tutorial. If you want the Tutorial sections then [Views](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/views/). [Templates](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to import sendsmile.py file into you main flask app file:

```
import sendsmile
...
@app.route('/sendsmile', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def sendsmile():
    sendsmile() #run sendsmile
return('', 200)
```

> HTML

```
{% extends "layout.html"%}
{% block content%}
<h1>about</h1>
<iframe name="iframe1" src="#"></iframe>
<a href="/sendsmile" target="iframe1">Start A.I.</a>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: if i import it into routes i get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sendsmile'

Comment: is send file in the same directory with app/main.py?

Comment: ok when i move it in the same fodler as the run.py file, as soon as i start running the py file the program starts, i want it to start when i click teh button and not before, also the window is basically a pop up window. its not rendered on the site. Even though i used the iframe